# Los cambios no se actualizan en el servidor

Tags: servidor, cache

Tengo que modificar un sitio que ya esta hecho, para añadir una nueva pagina y un enlace a ella. El problema es que subo los archivos y al entrar al sitio no aparecen los cambios.

He trabajado con otros sitios alojados en el mismo servidor y nunca me ha pasado esto ¿puede ser que el sitio este hecho con algun framework que tenga control de cache?, ¿como puedo saber si utliza algun framework y cual es? Estoy 99.9% seguro que no utiliza symfony porque ya he trabajo en otro proyecto en symfony y este no tiene la misma estructura de carpetas.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado a borrar la cache del navegador?

Comment: ctrl+shift+R suele solucionar muchas veces el día

Comment: Ha sido lo primero que hecho, el ctrl+shift+R, borrar la cache del navegador e incluso borrar web storage por descartar cosas. Tambien he accedido desde otro equipo y el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Se me ocurre que busques directorios cache y borres sus contenidos en caso de encontrarlos: "find / -type d -iname cache". Reinicia después el servidor apache (o el que utilices): "service apache2 restart"

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda. He conseguido dar con la soulción, el fichero que estaba modificando no era el mismo que estaba incluido en la pagina.